react i18n missingKey after successfully initialized
I'm using react-i18next in my react project, and In Project i18n was successfully initialized, but when I use useTranslation hook in my component, I still got missingKey error, I set the debug options to true in order to see the message of i18n when initialized.
Let me share the debug console message


Can anyone guess what is the problem?
Thank you very much
